How to find IP addresses for large mining sites？
How can I find the Bitcoin core IP addresses of large mining sites such as Foundryusa and Antpool, query transactions entering Mempool, and push my transactions in? Mempool.space hides some conflicting orders, which is no longer reliable!!!

Have you considered asking their support teams?
